# Program crashes when I use SDL_QUIT event?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have tried to write a code that creates a window which shows a particular image when pressed a particular arrow key and closes the window when the x button(on the screen) is clicked:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Gamestate
{
    Play, Exit
};

enum Keypress
{
    KEY_PRESS_DEFAULT,
    KEY_PRESS_UP,
    KEY_PRESS_DOWN,
    KEY_PRESS_RIGHT,
    KEY_PRESS_LEFT,
    KEY_PRESS_TOTAL,
};

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void run();

private:
    //data members
    int WINDOW_WIDTH;
    int WINDOW_HEIGHT;
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_TOTAL ];
    SDL_Surface* defaultSurface = NULL;
    Gamestate _gamestate;

private:
    //methods
    void init();
    void gameLoop();
    void processInput();
    void updateWindowSurface();
};

void error( string error1 )
{
    int itq;
    cout << error1 << endl;
    SDL_GetError();
    cout << endl << "Enter any key to quit" << endl;
    cin >> itq;
    SDL_Quit();
}

Game::Game()
{
    WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
    WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;
    _gamestate = Play;
}

void Game::run()
{
    init();
    gameLoop();

}

void Game::init()
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "GAME", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );

    if( window == NULL )
    {
        error( "SDL could not create a window!" );
    }
    screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( window );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        error( "SDL could not create a screen!" );
    }
    loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DEFAULT ] = SDL_LoadBMP( "press.bmp" );
    if( loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DEFAULT ] == NULL )
    {
        error( "Unable to load the Surface!" );
    }
    loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_UP ] = SDL_LoadBMP( "up.bmp" );
    if( loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_UP ] == NULL )
    {
        error( "Unable to load Image!" );
    }
    loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DOWN ] = SDL_LoadBMP( "down.bmp" );
    if( loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DOWN ] == NULL )
    {
        error( "Unable to load Image!" );
    }
    loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_RIGHT ] = SDL_LoadBMP( "right.bmp" );
    if( loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_RIGHT ] == NULL )
    {
        error( "Unable to load Image!" );
    }
    loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_LEFT ] = SDL_LoadBMP( "left.bmp" );
    if( loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_LEFT ] == NULL )
    {
        error( "Unable to load Image!" );
    }
    defaultSurface = loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DEFAULT ];
}

void Game::gameLoop()
{
    while( _gamestate != Exit )
    {
        processInput();
        updateWindowSurface();
    }
}

void Game::processInput()
{
    SDL_Event e;
    while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 )
    {
        if( e.type == SDL_QUIT )
        {
            _gamestate = Exit;
        }
        else if( e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN )
        {
            switch( e.key.keysym.sym )
            {
            case SDLK_UP:
                defaultSurface = loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_UP ];
                break;
            case SDLK_DOWN:
                defaultSurface = loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DOWN ];
                break;
            case SDLK_RIGHT:
                defaultSurface = loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_RIGHT ];
                break;
            case SDLK_LEFT:
                defaultSurface = loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_LEFT ];
                break;
            default:
                defaultSurface = loadSurface[ KEY_PRESS_DEFAULT ];
            }
        }
    }
}

void Game::updateWindowSurface()
{
    SDL_BlitSurface( defaultSurface, NULL, screenSurface, NULL );
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( window );
}

Game::~Game()
{
    for( int i = 0; i <= KEY_PRESS_TOTAL; i++ )
    {
        SDL_FreeSurface( loadSurface[ i ] );
        loadSurface[ i ] = NULL;
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    window = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
    return 0;
}
```

When I press the arrow keys the images which display is correct but when I try to close it, the program crashes. But when I try closing the window before pressing any arrow keys it works just fine.

Can any one help me with it?

Comment: Are you sure it crashed, or just closed? Did it give you get an error message?

Comment: It says game.exe has stopped working.

Comment: You are accessing `loadSurface` out of bounds, `i<=KEY_PRESS_TOTAL` should be `i<KEY_PRESS_TOTAL`.

Comment: @rafix07 I changed i<KEY_PRESS_TOTAL it worked! Thanks

Comment: Can I know why was that a mistake?

Comment: @Mersal Legal indices for an array are `0` to `size - 1`. Because the range is inclusive of 0, that makes `size` possible values. For example, if an array has a size of 3, there are three elements in that array. One each at index 0, 1 and 2. So when `i == KEY_PRESS_TOTAL` the index  `i` is out of bounds for `loadSurface[KEY_PRESS_TOTAL]`, the highest value allowed is `KEY_PRESS_TOTAL - 1`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you! Now I am clear.